# If only div 1 is clicked, play sound

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, I have a big div, and there is another div in that div as a shape.

When you click the shape, you did right and you have 1 point. When you click only the background div, I want to play a sound.

When I do (simple example):

```
var $audioLifeLost = new Audio('Mis.mp3');

#divid.onclick = function (){
$audioLifeLost.play();
}
```

it also plays the sound when I hit the shape because I hit both div's at the same time.

Anyway how can I do it?

Comment: If you only add a click listener to the inner div (your shape) it should not trigger when you click on the outside div!?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [stop the event from propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) up to the parent:

```js
document
  .querySelector('#inner')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('click inner');
    e.stopPropagation(); // <-- stop event propagation
  })

document
  .querySelector('#outer')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click outer');
  })
```

```css
#outer {
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  background: salmon;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer here. OP should look into event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("divid").onclick = function (e) {
  if (e.target == document.getElementById("divid"))
    $audioLifeLost.play();
}
```